# Bootstrap-Table loading by Json

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to reproduce it this example, but when I download files and try to play in local, not shown me the table, only show me the header, the title an two buttons (learn more and delete)

http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html
HTML:

```
   <table id="table"
       data-side-pagination="server"
       data-sort="desc"
       data-url="json/data1.json"
       >
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    url: 'json/data1.json',
    columns: [{
        field: 'id',
        title: 'Item ID'
    }, {
        field: 'name',
        title: 'Item Name'
    }, {
        field: 'price',
        title: 'Item Price'
    }, ]
});
```

JSON

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Item 0",
        "price": "$0"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Item 1",
        "price": "$1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Item 2",
        "price": "$2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Item 3",
        "price": "$3"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Item 4",
        "price": "$4"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Item 5",
        "price": "$5"
    }
]
```

I copied the folder bootstrap-table the bootstrap-table.js file because when I download the example was not in that folder.

someone could help me to know how to show table please

thanx

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to change the data-url for JSON data file with a table and do not load the JSON. I tried to load the JSON through a script rather than using data-url and not loaded me, I tried loading the contents of the JSON using the script, put the url of JSON and the data-url putting the file path and nothing

Comment: -_- i meant for you to share your code here or maybe in a jsfiddle

Comment: This is the code, sorry, I'm in a lot of things at the same time

Comment: There are literally millions of reasons for this to show the behavior you mentioned. Open your browser source inspector and start from there. There should be some errors in the console that explain what's going on.